# Cartoonize RGBA colors in a pixel array

Tags: c#, arrays, colors, unity-game-engine

I have a simple array in C# that stores RGBA colors that were captured from a webcam feed.

Each color has 4 values:

- Red
- Green
- Blue
- Alpha-channel(Transparency).

Is there a way to iterate over the array and *change the color values* in a way that  will make the picture look 'cartooned'? Maybe something like [**this**](https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2022/2218423404_60d0721b7c.jpg)?

I have the impression that this is generally done using some kind of shader or that cartoonization might also involve more complex effects - but i'd like to hear an opinion on just changing pixel color values for each pixel.

- Is this even possible?
- If yes is there a color-shifting - for lack of a better word -
  algorithm that can achieve this?

---

**Some context**: I'm working in Unity3D, I got the pixels using getPixels() off a WebCam Texture2D and the language is C#.

Comment: It'd require an algorithm but I think it's possible. This would make for a great problem over at code-golf.se Also saying you want a picture to be 'cartoonize' is ambiguous. The look of cartoons come in a myriad of variety.

Comment: let's not go crazy - clearly i'm not after a picture perfect cartoon but something that is good enough bearing in mind that I want to play just with colors. Furthermore I've added an example image - If you have something to contribute feel free to write an answer

Comment: Generally avoid asking Yes/No questions on SO, they tend to be not answerable or trivial to answer, or have a follow-up question (how to do it) anyway. I'd say: Yes, and most probably but nothing off-the-shelf.

Comment: The colors are not the big problem but if you start with a webcam image, how will you get those black strokes? They are what makes up the 'comics' look. I would start with a __color reduction__ to 10-20 colors, then do __edge detection__ to create the lines and finally try do __smooth__ them..

Comment: TaW's suggestion is certainly the easiest approach, but the results probably won't be "cartoony" enough for you.  There are a few algorithms for drawing caricatures which use computer vision techniques rather than filters to identify features and essentially redraw them in a cartoonish image.  I think that approach would look a lot better.  Your other issue is that web cams often take grainy pictures due to low light levels, and the extra noise will make edge detection very tricky.

Comment: @TaW - the color reduction might do the trick for me - it's worth to give it a shot. Can you describe it in more detail?

Comment: @RogerN Computer vision is a tricky and not-so-trivial subject. I'd rather try my luck with a color-reduction algorithm and then proceed from there..

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Try searching for [color quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) algorithms.

Comment: Indeed, Roger gives a good search word (quanatization). It can be coded or be found in probably most of the common image processing libs out there. To code it one usually scans the pixel colors to create a histogram and then keeps only the n most frequent colors, replacing the other by their closest matches.Edge detection is much tougher and I would certainly try to find a nice lib that can do all those filters,,

Comment: Also: Really god results usually call for a bit of gauging and selecting by a human.  What is your aim?

Comment: @TaW I'm working in Unity3D and using a library is not as easy as it sounds.  Also, I'm a strictly front-end dev who is only recently taking baby steps in C#. The aim is that my user takes a picture off his webcam - crops the image and adds it as the face of his avatar - the avatar bodies are cartoon-like structures so this calls for a cartoon-like face image to match

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes it possible to make the process slightly interactive then? So the user could could select from several versions or twist some knobs to find a nice avatar for himself..

Comment: @TaW That wouldn't be a bad idea tbh:)